# How to pass a java function returning void to a kotlin higher order function

Tags: interop

I have a function in kotlin that receive a function as parameter:

```
fun f(() -> Unit)
```

I need to call this function from Java and pass a function that return void:

```
//The function I want to pass
void myJavaFunction() {
   // Do Something
}

//calling the kotlin Higher Order function 
f(myJavaFunction())
```

This won't compile. 
The compiler stated: Found void. Required: kotlin.jvm.functions.Function()

So the question is how can I pass the java function to the kotlin function ?